# Don't ask about... Loopholes

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Christianity SE clearly states:

> Don't ask about whether some group or person is "Christian"

Over the past couple of days I've noticed one member consistently asking questions about whether one thing or another gave the Catholic Church cause to determine certain sects not to be Christian.

---

**Examples:**

In ["Are there any denominations that baptize ONLY in the Name of Jesus?"](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/33218/are-there-any-denominations-that-baptize-only-in-the-name-of-jesus/33219?noredirect=1#comment87239_33219)
OP edited their question:

[image]

Then from this Question: [What is the Catholic Church response to the question of the validity of Baptism conferred in the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/33245/what-is-the-catholic-church-response-to-the-question-of-the-validity-of-baptism/33247?noredirect=1#comment87278_33247) The OP left this comment below the accepted answer: *"From this, would you know if the Catholic Church considers Mormons as Christians?"*

Then today the same person made this comment: *"the question has come because I wanted to know what [church] community determines who is a member or not thereby will answer my question who is or is not a christian as determined by said community."* on this question: [According to the Catholic Church, who are those that belong to the full membership of the Church?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/33254/according-to-the-catholic-church-who-are-those-that-belong-to-the-full-membersh)

On each question I commented and reminded the member of the Christianity SE format, but on the third question I invited him into chat to address my concerns. In the chat, he insisted his questions were inside the format because, quote; **"I am just asking if *x* goes to make such a determination about *y*."** The *"y"* in each case appearing to be whether or not the Catholic Church determines a sect to be Christian based on the *"x"*.

I may be wrong about this, if so please correct me, but this appears to me to be an attempt to work around the, *Don't ask about whether some group or person is "Christian"* policy.

---

**Is it acceptable to ask if certain doctrines or practices cause specific denominations to determine other sects not to be Christian?**

Comment: I did a double-take at the diff and un-clickable link in your post until I viewed the source and saw that it was a screenshot. You fooled me.

Answer (score 8):

I don't see a problem.

While FMS originally did ask simply "would they be considered Christian?" from the rest of the question I think it's pretty clear they meant "considered Christian *by the people judging the baptisms*". DJClayworth fixed the ambiguity, so no harm done.

The other comments are all explicitly asking about how specific denominations judge whether someone is Christian, which is perfectly fine. We do that all the time here.